# how to detect uninstall system dialog in android app

Tags: android, android-intent

How to detect the uninstall system dialog of an app in another android app and its on cancel button click?
Is there any system intent for this?

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` is broadcast when an existing application package has been removed from the device. For more details, visit [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)

Comment: Is there any way to access the uninstall dialog? To detect the cancel uninstall button click?